# Link with hover dropdown menu for Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, touch, hyperlink

I've found an issue I just can't seem to solve.

I've got a navigation, 5 links in total. One of the links has a dropdown menu when you hover over it showing 3 more links.

Fine when a mouse is involved. But when you start using touch devices, the parent link consumes all gestures and taps, and the viewer is shown the dropdown for a fraction of a second before being taken to the parent's link page.

I'm wondering if there's a way of making it so the first touch of the parent link shows the dropdown menu, then a second touch would go to that link. touching anything else would just hide the dropdown.

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Anyone have any ideas? jQuery would be ideal

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps? You may want to customize the behavior of the dropdown, but this shows the basic logic of handling the click events and preventing default behaviour (i.e. following links) if the menu isn't open:

```
$(function() {
    $('#main-menu a').click(function(e) {
        var listItem = $(this).closest('li');
        if (!listItem.is('.open')) {
            // Opening drop-down logic here. e.g. adding 'open' class to <li>
            e.preventDefault();
            listItem.addClass('open');
        }
        // Otherwise the default behaviour of the event (clicking the link) will be unaffected
    });
});
```

Comment: Again, this removes the link once it's click, but doesn't re-instate the link once "open" has been applied... is there such a thing?

Comment: [Updated previous fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FXTgm/4/) to allow link to work first time if link doesn't have a sub-menu

Comment: Does this remove the hover functionality from the dropdown? This issue is related to touch devices as "hover" is fine desktops. Take a look at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mVVVM/14/). It works, but it doesn't hide the menu once you've clicked off of it

Comment: My example doesn't consider the hover event at all. It would be best to get the dropdown working how you want with only the click event to be certain it will work on mobile devices, THEN you should worry about making it work on hover as well (see [Continual Improvement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continual_improvement_process)).

Answer (score 0):

i have done complete bins for above issue also placed demo link here.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp72

**HTML**

```
<ul id="main-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          Sub Link
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          Sub Link
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          Sub Link
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('ul a').click(function(e) {
        $('#main-menu li').removeClass('open');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('li').addClass("open");
        var pos = $(this).closest('li.open').offset();
        $(this).closest('li.open').find("ul.sub-menu").css('top', pos.top + 'px');

    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#main-menu{
  list-style:none;
  margin:2px;
  padding:2px;
}
li{
  border:1px solid #333;
  background:#ebcdff;
  text-align:center;
  width:100px;
}
li:hover{
  background:#abcdfd;
}
li:hover a{
  color:#ff3322;
}
li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#2466ff;

}
li.open {
  background:#abcdfd;

}
li.open a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ff3322;

}
ul.sub-menu{
  list-style:none;
  display:none;
}
li.open > ul{
  position:absolute;
  left:70px;
  display:block;
}
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp72

Comment: This seems to stop all links working in all of the navigation, adding > solves the child issue:    $('#main-menu > a').click(function(e) However, it doesn't remove OPEN when it's finished.